# How do I fix an uneven butt?

Tags: weightlifting, squats

I'm 4'11 and 84 lbs and have been doing the 30 day squat challenge. I'm on day 25 and I noticed that the right side of my butt looks better than the left. It's rounder and more lifted. I was just wondering how I could balance them out.

Comment: Did your butt even out? And how long did it take if it did?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's pretty normal. Everyone tends to favor one side or the other -- usually your dominant side will be stronger.  One side may always be slightly more toned than the other, but you can make the difference much less noticeable by doing alternating unilateral movements such as [weighted lunges](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/DBLunge.html), [step ups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/DBStepUp.html), [pistols](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BWSingleLegSquat.html), [split squats](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BWSingleLegSplitSquat.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting solution for you might be to the following workout every 2nd day for 2 weeks.

Warm Up.

Do some dynamic stretches.

Then only on your right side do a static glute stretch, this is so that you weaken the muscle on the right side a little, but please take extreme care not to over stretch as that can cause injury during the workout.

Now do a single leg squat on your right leg without any weights and on your left leg add 5LB in each hand and do the same.

You can incorporate this in any workout you are doing if you feel it will help.

Another option to look at is to do yoga, I have seen a lot of results in that area on myself with yoga.

Comment: I am not a fan of doing asymmetric training to balance out imbalances, chances are that you simply cause to shift the problem to the other side. Also I am skeptical about your argument that stretching weakens muscles.

Comment: @Informaficker you are right to be concerned, and that's why I wrote "2 weeks" and I agree its not the best solution but good enough if you are trying to avoid cosmetic surgery, and in regards to static stretching, I did not mean say that it weakens the muscle in general but just enough to keep it at bay while working out which has been proven.